# Yii2, return records with the same values

Tags: sql, yii2

I'am trying to get all records from a table which have matching values. In my example below I need to find the products with the selected filters.

Results should be: looking for products with filters 'red' & 'black' and it should return id '38'.

```
$filters =['red','black'];
$products = Product::find();
$products->from(['p' => 'product']);
$products->leftJoin(['f'= 'filters'], 'f.item_id = p.id');
foreach( $filters as $filter) {
    // this works with 1 filter but not with more than 1
    $products->andWhere(['f.filter' => $filter]);
}


|------------|
| products   |
|------------|
| id | name  |
|------------|
| 34 | volvo |   
|------------|
| 35 | bmw   |  
|------------|  
| 36 | mazda |
|------------|  
| 37 | volvo |  
|------------|
| 38 | audi  |  
|------------| 

|-----------------------|
| filters               |
|-----------------------|
| id | item_id | filter |
|-----------------------|
| 1  | 38      | red    |  
|-----------------------|
| 2  | 38      | black  |  
|-----------------------|
| 3  | 35      | red    |  
|-----------------------|  
| 4  | 35      | white  |
|-----------------------|  
| 5  | 36      | white  |  
|-----------------------|
| 5  | 36      | red    |  
|-----------------------|
```

Comment: what it returns?

Comment: nothing if I use more than 1 filter

Answer (score 0):

All filter should create a separate join, you can not have 2 different values in the same filter record. And you should use `innerJoin` instead of `leftJoin`, otherwise you'll get records even if no filter matches. So correctly:

```
$filters =['red','black'];
$products = Product::find();
$products->from(['p' => 'product']);
foreach( $filters as $key => $filter) {
    $joinAlias = "f_$key";
    $products->innerJoin([$joinAlias => 'filters'], "$joinAlias.item_id = p.id");
    $products->andWhere(["$joinAlias.filter" => $filter]);
}
```

BTW: If you don't understant what happens, it is a good practice to check the generated SQL. Use `$products->createCommand()->getRawSql()` to see what SQL is generated and you can run it in directly to check the result